# How to simple test the file download and upload?

Tags: go, testing

I have two api for file download and upload. (`/static/{filename}` api for downloading, `/upload` api for uploading) For consistency, it need a test file to ensure the functionality of them two. I check the official fs_test.go, but it is too massive to use, is there a trick way to do it?

Comment: Do a GET request to test the download and a POST request to test the upload. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I tried to find a simple code to understand the workflow, and the official test guide is too massive for me to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a unit test? If you are supposed to test saving the file you can use a brute force.

1. Create file
2. Check if it exists (optional: check the file data)
3. Delete file